# How can I find an element by css selector in Angular2 (ngx)?

Tags: html, angular, css-selectors, angular5, angular2-services

How can I find an element by css selector in whole document, not only in child elements in Angular2 (ngx)?

Comment: Do `document.querySelectorAll(your_element);` into `ngOnInit()` will do the stuff

Answer (score 5, accepted):

first you will need to import the `ElementRef` from angular core,
then you can use the query selector method to get the element

```
import { ElementRef,OnInit} from '@angular/core';
     element;

constructor( private el: ElementRef) {}
ngOnInit() {
    this.HTMLElement: HTMLImageElement = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector(`#selector`);
  }
```

checkout these documentation on [ElementRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef) and [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement)

Caution from the angular documentation

> Use this API as the last resort when direct access to DOM is needed.
>   Use templating and data-binding provided by Angular instead.
>   Alternatively you can take a look at Renderer2 which provides API that
>   can safely be used even when direct access to native elements is not
>   supported.
>
> Relying on direct DOM access creates tight coupling between your
>   application and rendering layers which will make it impossible to
>   separate the two and deploy your application into a web worker.

Answer (score -2):

```
angular.element(element.getElementsByClassName("classname"));
```

Make sure you don't user period (.) before the class name.

Comment: The question said "CSS selector" not "class name"

Comment: Moreover this answer is for AngularJS 1.x, not Angular 2+